# MySQL group by summary

Tags: mysql, group-by

in my members table i would like a summary of all different people in "locations" 1 - 7 of how many people are online and offline.

```
SELECT location, COUNT(*) FROM members GROUP BY location;
```

that returns:

```
1 10  
2 5  
3 4  
4 12  
5 6  
6 3  
7 19
```

I would like a COUNT for members with a status of 0 (offline) and a status of 1 (online). how do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT location, status, COUNT(*) FROM members GROUP BY location, status
```

As one row:

```
SELECT
    location,
    COUNT(status) - SUM(status) as offline,
    SUM(status) as online
FROM members
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: this works but it creates two rows for each location, which would make it awkward in my php as i print this data out in a table.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT location, status, COUNT(*) FROM members GROUP BY location, status